# java date subtract hours - Period between two hours

Tags: java, date, netbeans

i can not find what I got wrong, it worked perfect with the same date
but when i enter a diferent date it makes a huge calculation. 
its for a parking lot software that i'm trying to do. to calculate the period between two hours

```
public void obtenerSalida(String fech, String fech_s,String hora_sal,String serie,String hora_e,
        javax.swing.JTextField periodo){

    String per;

    String dateStart =fech+" "+hora_e;
    String dateStop =fech_s+" "+hora_sal;

    System.out.println(dateStart);
    System.out.println(dateStop);


    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd 00:00:00");  

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    try {
        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000%60;         
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);         
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000); 

    if((diffMinutes>=1) && (diffMinutes<60)){
        periodo.setText(diffMinutes + " minuto(s).");
    }
    else
        if((diffMinutes>=60)&&(diffHours>=1 && diffHours<10)){
           per=diffHours+":"+(diffMinutes%60);
           periodo.setText(per);
        }

    System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");         
    System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");         
    System.out.println("Time in hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");
    System.out.println(""+diff);
}
```

Example

```
I enter this values
fech = 6/12/2016
fech_s = 7/12/2016
hora_e = 1:41:49
hora_s = 8:18:43
```

And i got this

```
6/12/2016 1:41:49
7/12/2016 8:18:43
Time in seconds: 54 seconds.
Time in minutes: 525996 minutes.
Time in hours: 8766 hours.
```

and i know it totally wrong. It could not have been so long

Comment: Your parser is wrong .. `yy/MM/dd 00:00:00` and you enter a `dd/MM/yy ...` What is the diff should represent ? Minutes could be > 59 ?

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Look at `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, and `Duration` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your date and date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd 00:00:00")
```

but you put the date in an other format.
rather use the format :

```
"d/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```